# Why do these coordinates not display correctly (or intersect correctly) with this boundary file?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, intersection, sf

This is a follow up to [my previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/293559/126188). I wrote code that imports the boundaries of a few US states, and, for some arbitrary point *within those boundaries*, buffers a circle around that point and then draws both on a map.\

Even though the latitude and longitude specified fall squarely within the boundaries, they don't appear this way on the map. **Am I using the wrong projection? I chose the Albers projection per [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/141580/126188).** I guessed that this may be the problem because the axes aren't in longitude and latitude either; they seem arbitrary.

This is the output, which is incorrect. The blue point/buffer should be in the northwest quadrant of the red map.

[image: erroneous map]

This is the code:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(USAboundaries)

albers_proj <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"

# download county boundaries
counties <- us_counties(map_date = "2000-01-01", resolution = "high", 
                        states = c("Utah", "New Mexico", "Colorado", "Arizona"))
counties <- counties %>% st_transform(albers_proj)

# example point
lon <- -111.101099
lat <- 40.477140
elev <- 150
tower <- st_point(x = c(lon, lat, elev), dim = "XYZ")
tower <- tower %>% st_sfc(crs = albers_proj)

# draw the radio horizon around the tower
scalar <- 3.57
radius <- scalar * sqrt(tower[[1]][3]) * 1000
tower_buffer <- st_buffer(tower, dist = radius)

xlim <- c(-2e06, 1e06)
ylim <- c(-6e05, 6e05)

png("map.png", width = 1100, height = 850, units = "px")
plot(st_geometry(counties), col = adjustcolor("maroon", alpha=0.5), xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, axes=TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(tower_buffer), col = adjustcolor("blue", alpha=0.5), add=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

Comment: You need to project the tower's location to the Albers CRS.

Comment: @mkennedy I thought that what this line did: `tower <- tower %>% st_sfc(crs = albers_proj)`? Or do I need to project `tower_buffer` as well? The projection won't pass through the buffering operation?

Comment: No, st_sfc just sets the coordinate reference system. You usually can't reproject without both input/output definitions (function would have to make an assumption).

Comment: @mkennedy Ah. If I change that line to `tower <- tower %>% st_sfc(crs = albers_proj) %>% st_transform(crs=albers_proj)`, however, the problem persists. I take it I'm using the wrong `st` function (instead of `sf_project`) to reproject?

Comment: Create a new crs that's nad83 (EPSG::4269) and use that in st_sfc. Then the st_transform should work. Right now input/output CRS are both albers.

Comment: maybe something like +init=epsg:4269 +proj=longlat +datum=nad83 +no_defs (cribbed off internet)

Comment: @mkennedy Thank you; I got it work using the same input projection as the county shapefiles. I'll post the completed code in answer for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [mkennedy's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293765/why-do-these-coordinates-not-display-correctly-or-intersect-correctly-with-thi?noredirect=1#comment471196_293765), I set the input projection to be consistent across both files, i.e. `"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"`, and then projected/transformed the tower location to the Albers projection.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(USAboundaries)

albers_proj <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"

# download county boundaries
counties <- us_counties(map_date = "2000-01-01", resolution = "high", 
                        states = c("UT", "NM", "CO", "AZ"))
input_proj <- st_crs(counties)$proj4string
plot(st_geometry(counties))
counties <- counties %>% st_transform(albers_proj)

lon <- -111.101099
lat <- 40.477140
elev <- 150
tower <- st_point(x = c(lon, lat, elev), dim = "XYZ")
tower <- tower %>% st_sfc(crs = input_proj) %>% st_transform(crs=albers_proj)

# draw the radio horizon around the tower
scalar <- 3.57
radius <- scalar * sqrt(tower[[1]][3]) * 1000
tower_buffer <- st_buffer(tower, dist = radius)

# transform back into the input projection for nice plotting
counties <- counties %>% st_transform(crs=input_proj)
tower_buffer <- tower_buffer %>% st_transform(crs=input_proj)

plot(st_geometry(counties), col = adjustcolor("maroon", alpha=0.5), axes=TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(tower_buffer), col = adjustcolor("blue", alpha=0.5), add=TRUE)
```

The corrected map looks like this:

[image: ![corrected map]