# Plotting and analyzing extracted elevation data in R?

Tags: raster, r, elevation, zonal-statistics

I have a shapefile of county boundaries for New York state and elevation data downloaded through the `elevatr` package.

```
library(elevatr)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(USAboundaries)

counties <- us_counties(map_date = "1930-01-01", resolution = "high", states = c("NY"))

counties_sf <- as(counties, "Spatial")
elevation_data <-get_elev_raster(counties_sf, z=9, src = "aws")
map <- extract(elevation_data, counties)
plot(elevation_data, axes=TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(counties), add=TRUE)
```

This produces an image like this:

[image: New York elevation data]

That's all well and good, but how do I restrict the elevation data to just the area of the county boundaries, e.g. for computing zonal statistics or for creating a map of *only* the state?

The `extract` function from the `raster` package returns a sequential list of lists of elevation points, but as far as I can tell, there isn't a way to link those points *back* to the unique IDs of the actual counties that come from the shapefile, even using the `extent` function.

Ideally I'd like to work with everything using the `sf` (Simple Features) package, as in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/293765/126188), because that's what I'm most familiar with. It's a little confusing for me to keep track of which packages return raster objects, which return sf objects, which return spatial polygon data frames, etc.

Comment: use fasterize to create an index raster with the polygon id, then it's data frame stuff in a table of the cells/values/polygon

Comment: @mdsumner I'll give the `rasterize` function a try (it's running now). Then it should be straightforward to convert everything into simple features. If I get it all to work, I'll post the completed code too, for future reference.

Comment: @mdsumner I assume "fasterize" is a slip of the fingers? Sounds like a very useful function...

Comment: not a slip, it's a game changer - package has been on CRAN for a while, and raster-dev is incorporating the technique for a future release

Comment: @mdsumner My mistake. According to the documentation, `fasterize` converts an `sf` object **to** a `raster` object, which sounds like the opposite of what I want. Can you give me a short example of how it works in this context?

Comment: Are you trying to summarize the values within each polygon, or do you need to export a table of each pixel value within each polygon?

Comment: @dbaston For now I'm trying to summarize the values within each polygon, in a way that isn't limited to just the mean, median, etc. (ideally I'd be able to apply custom functions) but longer-term I'll need to do some nearest-neighbor sort of calculations with the elevation data.

Comment: If you burn the polygon ID (make a row number on the sf object) into the raster with fasterize, then you can use the values of the raster (your original) and the values of the fasterize output one-to-one - the polygonID is a grouping variable for the values. It's just one level of abstraction away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from your code I'd use `fasterize` to very quickly get an index of what is polygon and what is not. You don't need the grouping so even the `NA` identification would be enough, but if you need elevation grouped by polygon this index is already suitable.

Please note the **destructive** step that updates the `elevatr` data set in this code, just so it looks right (masked).

```
library(fasterize)
counties_sf$POLYID <- 1:nrow(counties_sf)
polymap <- fasterize(counties_sf, elevation_data, field = "POLYID")
## mask out elevation where there's no polygon
elevation_data[is.na(values(polymap))] <- NA
plot(elevation_data)
```

Grouping, for example:

```
## to get zonal stats
library(dplyr)
tibble(value = values(elevation_data), POLYID = values(polymap)) %>% 
dplyr::filter(!is.na(value)) %>% group_by(POLYID) %>% 
summarize(mean(value))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can summarize values within each polygon by passing a custom function to the `extract` function in the `raster` package, or the `exact_extract` function in the [`exactextractr`](https://github.com/isciences/exactextractr) package (much faster, handles pixels partially covered by polygons.)

The `raster::extract` function expects a summarizing function with the signature `function(x, na.rm)`, e.g.:

```
counties$second_lowest_point <- extract(
 elevation_data,
 counties, 
 fun=function(x, na.rm) {
   if (na.rm) { 
     sort(na.omit(x))[2]
   } else {
     sort(x)[2]
   }
 })
```

The `exactextractr::exact_extract` function expects a summarizing function with the signature `function(x, w)`, where `w` is the fraction of the pixel that is covered by the polygon. Here we're taking the area-weighted mean of elevations > 400m:

```
counties$mean_elevation_over_400 <- exact_extract(
  elevation_data,
  counties,
  fun=function(x, w) { weighted.mean(x[x > 400]) })
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. I guess the Simple Features package doesn't support methods like this yet, right?

Comment: Both `raster` and `extactextractr` operate on `sf` objects from the Simple Features package. `raster` does so by copying the data from `sf` to `sp` objects; `exactextractr` operates on `sf` objects directly.