# Choosing projection for Continental United States?

Tags: coordinate-system, united-states

I'm working on some code that maps data across the continental US.

I need to project things with a unit length of feet, ex: EPSG:26916.

Is there a projection like 26916 that works for all of the US?

As far as I can tell there are longitude limits for accuracy with 26916.

Comment: As a starting point, check here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141580/which-projection-is-best-for-mapping-the-contiguous-united-states. Choosing a projection is quite a broad topic, and often there is no "correct" answer. It usually boils down to whether you want to preserve distance, shape, angle, or can be satisfied with a compromise.

Comment: That's UTM - definitely not appropriate for the continent. UTM is poor choice usually, but we have to align with it because so many local authorities adopted it long ago. More discussion https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/reproj-geo-data.html#which-crs-to-use

Answer (score 3):

I'd start with [EPSG:2163](http://epsg.io/2163) aka US National Atlas equal area, this fulfils all of your needs except it is in metres not feet. But that is a simple multiplication fix (unless you are [NASA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter)).

### Update

This looks like it has been replaced by [EPSG:9311](https://epsg.io/9311)

Comment: This is deprecated now. Any new suggestions @Ian?