# Buffer set of lines in meters that span the entire USA

Tags: coordinate-system, buffer

I imported a shapefile with lines that span the USA.  The CRS comes in as EPSG:4326-WGS84. I want to buffer all the lines by 600 meters. The Buffer tool suggests reprojecting since only degree unit are available for this projection.  Is there a CRS that supports meters for the entire USA?

[image: USAlines]

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141580/which-projection-is-best-for-mapping-the-contiguous-united-states

Comment: You should state what GIS tool you are using (via a tag, maybe). Also give the exact error message.